# From JQuery to JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want the array of objects result (**msg**) that I get from AJAX into a JS variable (**allEvents**)

I thought it could be done like this:

```
let allEvents;

$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "https://someApiToGetData.com",
})
   .done(function (msg) {
      allEvents = msg;
   });

console.log(allEvents);
```

I get *Undefined* as a result on the console. So the part `allEvents = msg;` wasn't as easy as I thought.

If I try `console.log(msg)` I get what I want. But I just want msg in that allEvents JS variable so I can handle the results.

Is there any way to get **msg** into **allEvents**?

Comment: Everything must happen inside your `.done(function(msg){ /* in here in this case */ });`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An ajax request is asynchronous, which means that your last line will run before the ajax request has returned, that's why `allEvents` is undefined, if you modify your code to print `allEvents` inside `done` you'll see all events has the correct data.

```
let allEvents;

$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "https://someApiToGetData.com",
})
   .done(function (msg) {
      allEvents = msg;
      console.log(allEvents);
   });
```